# PFUser Query Contraint

Tags: parse-platform

This is my current query:

```
[PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"phone" containedIn:phones];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.

        self.contactsWithApp = objects;




        [self.tableView reloadData];



    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

I am searching for users according to an array composed of phone number strings.  The key 'phone' in my User class contains a phone number string for each user.  Why is this not working?

Comment: Are you sure your phone key in Parse is of the string type? Double check in your data browser.

Comment: Also, are you calling one of the findObjects methods to actually execute the query? We need some more details and please include some code.

Comment: Yes, it is of string type

Comment: What about my 2nd comment?

Comment: just added some code, i am using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Comment: Is the error logging to the console, and if yes then what is it logging as?

Comment: Depending on the permissions set up, you may not have "Find" permission on the User class. In this case it will return an empty `objects` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead. This is assuming that the class you are querying in Parse is called User.

Replace your line of:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
```

With this:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
```

Final code:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[userQuery whereKey:@"phone" containedIn:phones];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.

    self.contactsWithApp = objects;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

} else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
}];
```

Comment: hmm, still same result

Comment: What is the result? Is an error actually showing up in the console?

Comment: there is no error, there are just no objects in the NSArray

Comment: If there is no error, then none of the phone number strings in your array are being found in Parse's "phone" key. Could you edit your original post, and show me what one of your array's phone number strings looks like? Particularly the one that is in the array that you know is also in Parse. Also, copy/paste what that number in parse looks like.

Comment: @user3344977 I have the same problem, with equalTo: I can get PFUser, but with containdIn:friendIDs - no user

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this question isn't actual anymore. But I faced with the same problem and want to share with solution. Most likely that you have got JSON response, and your 'phone' in phones - is NSNumber type. To query from Parse with `containedIn:` array must be with objects of type NSString.